# How can I automatically reload the page in angular after showing a snackbar

Tags: javascript, angular

Good evening, I have a question that I want to ask the question is that I want my angular application to automatically reload after a snackbar appears that lasts a certain time, this after executing a delete action.

```
export class PrtgFormService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
              private snackBar: MatSnackBar,) { }


      config: MatSnackBarConfig = {
      duration: 4000,
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      verticalPosition: 'bottom',    
      }


    success(msg: any) {                                            
        this.config['panelClass']='equipo_success';
        this.snackBar.open(msg, '',this.config);
          } 

  }
```

```
// Funcion que genera la ventana modal para confirmar eliminar algun elemento/objeto en particular.Recibe como parametro el objeto en cuestion.


    onDelete(element:any) {
        this.msgEquipo='¿Esta seguro que desear eliminar este equipo?';
        this.PrtgServiceForm.openConfirmDialogDelete(this.msgEquipo).afterClosed().subscribe(res =>{ // Si en caso afirmativo se presiona el boton SI en el dialogo de eliminar equipo, la variable res=true y se hace la peticion al servicio HTTP Delete.
          if(res){
              this.PrtgService.deleteEquipo(element).subscribe();
              this.msg="Equipo Eliminado con exito";
              this.PrtgServiceForm.success(this.msg);
              console.log(res)
                }

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `afterDismissed` method of mat-snackbar. use this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api) for more details.

```
success(msg: any) {
    this.config['panelClass'] = 'equipo_success';
    let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(msg, '', this.config);

    snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
        // Reload your application here
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example, since the information in the documentation is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

In your onDelete method maybe you can use

```
onDelete(element:any) {
        this.msgEquipo='¿Esta seguro que desear eliminar este equipo?';
        this.PrtgServiceForm.openConfirmDialogDelete(this.msgEquipo).afterClosed().subscribe(res =>{ // Si en caso afirmativo se presiona el boton SI en el dialogo de eliminar equipo, la variable res=true y se hace la peticion al servicio HTTP Delete.
          if(res){
              this.PrtgService.deleteEquipo(element).subscribe();
              this.msg="Equipo Eliminado con exito";
              this.PrtgServiceForm.success(this.msg);
              console.log(res)
              location.reload();
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the afterDismissed () method for snackbar, I can't apply this.snackbar.afterDismissed () in function success(msg)